# Is there a way to use contenteditable attribute in <td> element in vuetify Datatable component

Tags: datatable, vuetify.js, contenteditable

I want to use in line editing option in Vuetify Datatable component instead of opening a dialog box for editing.
Is there a way to use contenteditable attribute in  element in vuetify Datatable component.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable  you can apply contenteditable attribute to any HTMLElement.

Try adding the attribute to the element you want to edit.

eg

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify has an inbuild content editable mode.

[**DOCS**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#content-editing)

The idea is that in every slot you add a `v-edit-dialog` and `v-text-field` and then sync the data using `v-model and return-value.sync`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used the following  code , and editing is working but not saved:  <template v-slot:item.name="props">
<td contenteditable="true" v-model="props.item.name"> {{props.item.name}}</td>        
        </template>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using contenteditable attribute, I used the following code and worked perfectly (editable without opening a dialog box and save to bind variable)

```
<template v-slot:item.name="props">
<v-text-field v-model="props.item.name"> </v-text-field>    
</template>
```